# Cascade operation in OneToOne Relationship which is confusing

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I have two related objects:

**User**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="userProfileImage")
 */
protected $profileImage;
```

**File**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profileImage")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userProfileImage", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $userProfileImage;
```

and two related records in my database. I would like to remove the old File object and replace it with the new File. The problem is I can not remove the File object, because I have the following error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'MyBundle\Entity\User#profileImage' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: MyBundle\Entity\File@000000001604d7ad000000003cc76066. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'MyBundle\Entity\File#__toString()' to get a clue.

In my opinion removing should work after calling:

```
$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->remove( $user->getProfileImage() );
$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->flush();
```

I tried to add `cascade={"all"}` and `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` to `$profileImage` annotation but without success. I need someone to explain me what I'm doing wrong and how I should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
To remove a related object, I shouldn't delete it directly:

```
$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->remove( $file );
```

but through by user:

```
$userFile = $user->getProfileImage();
$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->remove( $userFile );
$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->remove( $file );
```

Moreover, it was necessary to call `flush()` before and after the code above:

```
$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->flush();

$userFile = $user->getProfileImage();
$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->remove( $userFile );
$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->remove( $file );

$this->getDoctrine()-getManager()->flush();
```

I don't know why, but it works fine for me and maybe it will be usefull for someone else.

It doesn't change the fact, that it is a very ugly solution, so if someone knows how to improve this code, let me know! I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if that is the solution but i thik it should rather explicitly tell to cascade on delete

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profileImage", cascade={"persist", "remove")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userProfileImage", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $userProfileImage;
```